# Change selected text color of individual element

Tags: javascript, css

This may not be possible, but I'd like to confirm.

You can globally change the selected text highlight color of the page with

```
::selection {
    background: #cccccc;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

but is it possible to change the the highlighted color for an individual element in JavaScript?

For example, if `s` is an element's style attribute, you can change the text and background colors using

```
s.color = s.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
```

is there a style to change the element's highlight color?

This must be in old-fashioned JavaScript, no JQuery.

**EDIT:**
Also, because of performance, I need to change this to the element itself.  CSS class swapping performs very poorly.  The use case is that every word in a page I do not own will become it's own element.  On an average page, adding a CSS class through script is taking 20-30 seconds whereas changing inline styles can be done in under 1.

Comment: Do you need to select each element in another color? Or will they be the same color/style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes aren't in the DOM, but you can use classes to achieve your result.

So add a rule like

```
.selectionclass::-moz-selection {
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

to your stylesheet and add the class name `selectionclass` to your element.

Comment: But can this be done with JavaScript, not through the addition of a class to the element.  Without going into too much detail, I have to do this for thousands of elements on a page, and the add/remove class method is dramatically less performant (if that's a word) than change the individual element's style.  I will add this to the question.  great approach though.  +1 for the solution given the info I provided.

Comment: Just saw your comment regarding pseudo elements in the DOM.  So the verdict is "not possible"?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. In order to style an element's pseudo-class or pseudo-elements you need a selector in a stylesheet, not inline style. Sorry :/